# Restricting view of content to one role

Tags: 8, nodes, users

I know how to change edit and create permissions of a content type to one role.

But what i need is that a user that has the role 'consultant' is the only one that can see the content that was created of the type 'consultant info'.

I can only find a way to watch "own published content" but that isnt enough because their are multiple consult accounts that need to see each-others content.

Ive already looked at modules like content_Access but they also don't provide this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry missunderstood your questtion, I think ->

https://www.drupal.org/project/node_view_permissions

is what you are looking for.

[image]